# How to excel file download with axios vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to download an excel file. I have used axios for it.

Below is my code:

```
reportExcel(val) {
  axios
    .get("/algn/api/report/" + val)
    .then((res) => {
      var url = res.data; // http://localhost.local/public/files/data.xlsx
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = url.split("/").pop();
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

I am getting the error as "Excel cannot open the file "data.xlsx" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file". (The original excel file is still usable).

I have tried all the solutions which I found in google but nothing worked. Please help. Thanks

Comment: use `location.href = url` easier i think. Do you tried it before?

Comment: So, it would be `var url = res.data;location.href = url`